# CodeIgniter validation errors specific to a form with multiple forms on a page

Tags: validation, codeigniter

I have a set of tabbed forms with validation and shared fields like title, description and tags that submit to the same controller method. I have separate validation and all that worked out and the tab with the form you submitted is active when you come back.

Here is the trick, right now since CI errors are a global function when I print them out with "echo form_error('title');" it shows the error on all the tab forms even though you only submitted one. For usability I want to limit the error to just the form submitted.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use whatever logic that you're using to show the active tab to hide the errors that are appearing on the fields in the inactive tab.

Another way would be to prepend the rules and field names with a identifier of the form that submitted them.  Something like...

```
in controller...
$this->form_validation->set_rules("{$tab}_title", 'Title', 'required|trim');

in view...
<?= form_open("{$tab}_title", set_value($this->input->post("{$tab}_title"))) ?>
<?= form_error("{$tab}_title") ?>
```